# Gnuplot : Fitting two data sets on each others

Tags: gnuplot

I have too data sets `x F(x)` and `x G(x)` and want to find, for instance, the optimal `a` such as `F(x)=G(a.x)` (can be applied in a similar fashion to any functional of G).

Now I understand that the `fit` function of gnuplot relies on fitting an analytical form of a function to a data set, so I guess my exact question is :

#### Can I 'spawn' a function with my first data set that I would use to fit on the second ?

Something like (pseudo-code) :

```
f(x)='data_set1.dat'(x)
g(x)=f(a*x)
fit f(x), 'data_set2.dat' via a
```

I guess any kind of interpolation (polynomial, etc.) could give me the ability to spawn such a function, but it seems like an awful-lot of trouble (and approximations).

Comment: No, I think you cannot do this with gnuplot. We had a similar question several months ago, but with no answer.